# FormatExcpetion from Azure Webjobs Host

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

Understand this is pre-release :)

When trying to use `QueueInput` in Azure WebJobs and sticking the hex string of a hash in the message.

```
public System.Guid GetOwner(CloudQueueMessage msg)
```

Looking at `ilspy` seems like it is trying to parse out `$AzureJobsParentId` and the JSON parser is throwing the exception I can get around it by encoding my hash in a JSON snippet but I'd prefer not to. Is this a known bug?

Comment: Can you please share the signature of your job function? What are the parameter types that you are binding?

Comment: I am getting the exact same problem. Every 2 minutes the jobs restart because of that error even if no message is added to the queue. I followed carefully every step to create a webjob, it really puzzle me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QueueInput] will normally use JSON.Net to deserialize the queue message payload to the parameter type. So if the queue message is not JSON, you'll get a exception (which should then be wrapped in something more friendly).

You can also work around it by using a string parameter with [QueueInput], like:

```
    public static void Function([QueueInput] string testqueue)
    {
    }
```

For string parameter, the SDK will give you the QueueMessage.AsString directly, without any JSON serialization.

FYI, $AzureJobsParentId is a special field placed on json payloads that identifies which function instance enqueued a message. This gets used when you enqueue a message with [QueueOutput]. You can then view that relationship in the SDK dashboard (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2014/01/27/getting-a-dashboard-for-local-development-with-the-webjobs-sdk.aspx)

Comment: I did actually use the string parameter (exactly lie your code) so this still might be a bug in the alpha but the rest of your info is good.

Comment: The parser exception should be caught within the SDK. Is it bubbling back to your code? In other words, is the concern here that the sdk should not be throwing exceptions internally

Comment: The only thing I am doing different from your exemple Mike is that I use [QueueInput("testqueue")] string message. Can this have an impact?